# PySide2 QGraphicsView zoom widget in scene macOS

Tags: python, pyside2, qgraphicsview

Apparently, a widget inside a QGraphicsView does not scale correctly on macOS. Does anyone have a workaround?

Problem:

I have a `QGraphicsView` where I am zooming by calling the `scale` method.

I also have some `QWidgets` in my `QGraphicScene`, but their UI graphics do not scale accordingly when I zoom.

I use a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` from within a `QGraphicsItem` to display the widgets, but the scale issue persists even by using the `scene.addWidget`.

[image: scale zoom issue]

I tested the code on macOS 10.15.7 and 10.14.6, both Intel CPUs.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments by musicamante, the `QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations` does the exact opposite, so I am taking the reference out of the question to avoid confusion since it was only a failed attempt.

Edit2: On Windows 10 seems to work fine.

[image: windows_os]

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainterPath, QColor, QBrush
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QGraphicsItem,
    QPushButton,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsProxyWidget
)


class NodeGraphicsContent(QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWidget(QPushButton('QGraphicsItem Button'))


class GraphicsItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.item_body = self.draw_item()
        self.draw_content()

    def draw_content(self):
        NodeGraphicsContent(self)

    def draw_item(self):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
        return path

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("#FF313131")))
        painter.drawPath(self.item_body)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.item_body.boundingRect()


class GraphicScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.scene_width = 500
        self.scene_height = 500

        self._grid_pattern = QBrush(QColor("#282828"), Qt.Dense7Pattern)

        self.setBackgroundBrush(QColor("#393939"))
        self.setSceneRect(-self.scene_width // 2, -self.scene_height // 2,
                          self.scene_width, self.scene_height)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        super().drawBackground(painter, rect)
        painter.fillRect(rect, self._grid_pattern)


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        """Zoom function."""
        zoom_factor = 1.25
        zoom_out = 1 / zoom_factor
        zoom_factor = zoom_factor if event.delta() > 0 else zoom_out
        self.scale(zoom_factor, zoom_factor)


class MainWidgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = GraphicScene()
        self.view = GraphicsView(self.scene)

        _layout = QVBoxLayout()
        _layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(_layout)

        self.add_widgets()

    def add_widgets(self):
        """Add first a normal widget, then a QGraphicsItem, 
        which both dont seem to scale correctly.
        """
        button = self.scene.addWidget(QPushButton('Widget Button'))
        button.setPos(-50, -100)
        self.scene.addItem(GraphicsItem())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(MainWidgets())
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Zoom with mouse wheel')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: In the code example I provided, the class NodeGraphicsContentRoot is what I tried to implement based on the other question I found. Still, I did not finish implementing the boundingRect and paint since I am unsure if it needs to be implemented since it is a "fake item".

Comment: The `ItemIgnoresTransformations` results in the item never being scaled, so its geometry and contents are always the same, no matter if the scene (or any parent item) is transformed (including scaling). If you don't want that, why are you using it?

Comment: Because I am trying to find a way to fix it and thought it could be pointing me in the right direction. Compared to not having it at all, it seemed to produce a more desirable result since the button stays in ratio with its label.

Comment: If you want scaling, you must *not* set the `ItemIgnoresTransformations` to any item unless you *specifically* want to *ignore* transformations for them. Widgets added to a scene are always automatically scaled, you don't have to fix anything, just add them with `addWidget()` or through QGraphicsProxyWidget. With the latter, adding the parent to the constructor is enough to make it a child of that parent. I strongly suggest you to start with basic experiments with QGraphicsView in order to better understand how it works, before trying to change somebody else's code you still don't understand.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your insight and time, but the flag `ItemIgnoresTransformations` came after trying to solve my issue. I discovered it when searching for other similar questions. I thought it might help, but it does not, hence my question on SO. As I stated in the question, I am using either a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` or the `scene.addWidget`, which neither work (watch the first GIF), so I don't understand your statement, "Widgets added to a scene are always automatically scaled". Does the example I provided work for you? Also, I don't get what you mean by "changing some else code"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244382/discussion-between-virgil-sisoe-and-musicamante).